# getting the list of the saved session in putty using plink

Tags: putty, plink

I am trying to write my scripts under windows to control putty.
Say I have a session called mySession. I can send a command to it using:

```
plink -load mySession -l myUserName -pw myPassowrd ps -ef
```

Now say I have many different sessions saved. is there a way to loop through the list of all my sessions to run this command?

Many thanks

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, the sessions are stored in the registry (`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\SimonTatham\PuTTY\Sessions`). At least it is the case in my environment here. You could for example use a batch script to access the session names.

```
@echo OFF
setlocal ENABLEEXTENSIONS
set KEY_NAME="HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\SimonTatham\PuTTY\Sessions"

FOR /F "usebackq" %%A IN (`REG QUERY %KEY_NAME% 2^>nul`) DO (
    FOR /F "tokens=6 delims=\" %%B IN ("%%A") DO (
        @echo ON
        "C:\Program Files\PuTTY\PLINK.EXE" -load %%B -l my_user -pw my_password ps -ef
        @echo OFF
    )
)
```

I used `tokens=6` to only get the last part of the path (`%%A`). I'm not much fimiliar with batch scripting therefore I don't even know if you need `setlocal ENABLEEXTENSION`.

If you know your session names you could also simply use the following command:

```
FOR %%A IN (session1_name session2_name session3_name) DO "C:\Program Files\PuTTY\PLINK.EXE" -load %%A -l my_user -pw my_password ps -ef
```

Hope this helps, even though your post is nearly one year old. Comments to improve the code are welcome.